Tasks.WhenAll(tasks) is not catching any exception
I am new to C# and Windows Forms.
I am using syncfusion C# library to encrypt / decrypt Word files.
I am using Async / Await tasks to decrypt files in bulk.
I have no problem to encrypt / decrypt one file or to encrypt multiple files.
I encountered the problem when trying to decrypt multiple word files or in bulk.
When decrypting one file with a wrong password, I get an exception and everything works fine.
But during bulk files decryption using await Task.WhenAll(tasks) inside try-catch block, I am not getting any exception while from the first task (first file to decrypt) I should get an exception because the password is wrong.
During entire week I tried most of the provided solutions everywhere but not successful and I don't know what I have to do.
Thank you very much!
The code should throw an exception when the first task is not successful but it's not.
GetPathOrExtention gte = new GetPathOrExtention();

private void DecryptDOCXFiles(string fileName)
{
    FileStream inputStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    WordDocument document = new WordDocument(inputStream, FormatType.Docx, TbDecPwd1.Text);

    FileStream outputStream = new FileStream(gte.GetDirPath(fileName) + "\\" + gte.GetfileName(fileName).Replace("Encrypted-", ""), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    document.Save(outputStream, FormatType.Docx);
    inputStream.Close();
    outputStream.Close();
}

private async Task DecryptWordFiles()
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Filter = "docx files (*.docx)|*.docx|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    ofd.Multiselect = true;
    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    if (TbDecPwd1.Text != "" && ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        foreach (string file in ofd.FileNames)
        {
            if (gte.GetFileExtension(file) != ".docx")
            {
                LblProceeding.ResetText();
                MessageBox.Show("Files version is not supported!" + '\n' + '\n' + "Only Word version 2019 and above are supported!", "P-GEN", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return;
            }

            if (gte.GetFileExtension(file) == ".docx")
            {
                LblProceeding.Text = "Proceeding... Do not exit the software!";
                var task = Task.Run(() => DecryptDOCXFiles(file)).ContinueWith(p => progressBar1.PerformStep());
                tasks.Add(task);
            }
        }
    }
    try
        {
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);  
            LblProceeding.Text = "Done!";
            MessageBox.Show("Files Successfully Decrypted!", "P-GEN", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            LblProceeding.ResetText();
            progressBar1.Visible = false;     
        }

    catch (AggregateException)
    {
        LblProceeding.ResetText();
        MessageBox.Show("Ensure the password is correct!" + '\n' + '\n' + "Ensure the files you want to decrypt are not opened in another software!", "P-GEN", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return;
    }

    catch (Exception)
    {
        LblProceeding.ResetText();
        MessageBox.Show("Ensure the password is correct!" + '\n' + '\n' + "Ensure the files you want to decrypt are not opened in another software!", "P-GEN", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return;
    }           
}

private void BtnWordFilesDec_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _ = DecryptWordFiles();
}


Please provide a [mcve] - which shouldn't need to perform any I/O, or use a UI at all. Just a console app with one faulted task and other non-faulted tasks, showing Tasks.WhenAll returning a task which doesn't end up faulting.

(Are you sure the problem isn't that you're using Task.ContinueWith, and the continuation isn't faulting, even if the original task is faulted?)

Yes I am sure the Task.ContinueWith is not the issue because it works fine when I input the correct password

That doesn't mean it isn't the problem that's stopping you from seeing faults in the original tasks. Have you tried without the ContinueWith call?

I've now provided a console app which provides pretty good evidence that Task.ContinueWith is the problem.

The problem is that the tasks you're awaiting are the result of calling Task.ContinueWith - and all of those complete without faulting. You don't care about the status of the continuation - you care about the statuses of the original tasks.
Here's a console application showing the same behavior:
var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
    .Select(ComputeDivision)
    .Select(t => t.ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine($"Task status: {t.Status}")))
    .ToList();

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
Console.WriteLine("All tasks completed");

async Task ComputeDivision(int index)
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(index + 1));
    Console.WriteLine($"Index: {index}; Division: {100 / index}");
}

As written, that completes and prints "All tasks completed". If you comment out the ContinueWith call instead, you'll see the failure. (i.e. it'll print the wrapped DivideByZeroException and not print "All tasks completed".)
Similarly, if you remove your call to ContinueWith, you'll be waiting for the original tasks to complete, and the resulting task will end up being faulted if any of the original tasks is faulted.
You can change the continuation to fail if the preceding task has failed by calling Wait on it - so in your code, this would be:
.ContinueWith(p => { progressBar1.PerformStep(); p.Wait(); })

That's somewhat ugly, admittedly... but then so is the use of Task.Run here, IMO. (I'd do the whole thing with asynchronous IO to start with, making DecryptDOCXFiles async, if you possibly can.)
There may be a better way of making the continuation propagate the original task status, but I don't know it offhand.

Thank you very much Jon!! May God offer you all the help you need!!
